# Obtener el valor HSV de un pixel

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy utilizando Python y OpenCV y mi intención es coger el valor HSV de un píxel:

Imagen original:
[image: Imagen HSV]

Imagen HSV (`hsv`):
[image: Imagen original]

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv[47,115])
>> [ 98 245 202]
```

El valor que me devuelve, `[ 98 245 202]`, está en BGR (RGB invertido), pues si lo pinto como RGB me pinta el color amarillo ya que pertenece a un círculo amarillo, por lo tanto no me devuelve el valor HSV.

¿Sabe alguien por qué devuelve el valor en BGR en vez de HSV? Se supone que la variable `hsv` debe de contener una matriz con los valores HSV y no BGR.

Answer (score 2):

La matriz que te devuelve esta bien,son valores HSV, 98 es el tono, como en OpenCV la escala de tonos es de 0 a 179 el angulo es de aproximadamente 197° un azul, cercano al cian, con valores de saturación y brillo altos, la escala para estos dos son de 0 a 255, por lo que los valores [98 245 202] están bien. Saludos